# Plotting forcasted data in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a plot in R of forecasted data against the actual data in R, but I keep getting a completely incorrect graph. I am trying to graph the actual values, forecast values, and the upper and lower prediction limits, all on the same graph. And then graph the prediction for the next year. This is the code I have:

```
ts.plot(housend, fcst$mean, ts(fcst$lower,start=2007), ts(fcst$upper,start=2007), 
        level=95, col=c(1,2,4,4))
```

I am trying but it is not working correctly. I have the "fcst" variable set at a 95% level.

Comment: This is not reproducible. You could plot the time series first, and then use `lines` or `points` to add predictions and CIs. See `?plot.ts` why your attempt will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do forecast by `arima`, `HoltWinters`, `ets` or many other tools, they usually incorporate own interface to `plot` function with everything you asked. You just need to call the `plot` function from the object given by a tool. For example:

```
fit <- Arima(WWWusage, order=c(3,1,0))
plot(fit)
```

or

```
fit <- ets(USAccDeaths)
plot(fit)
```